# I am struggling to write a Powershell script that queries last log on for a user across all Domain Controllers

Tags: powershell

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties lastLogon,EmailAddress | Select samaccountname,EmailAddress, @{Name="lastLogon";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.'lastLogon')}} |Out-Gridview
```

I want to able to write the above in  Powershell function so I can query the information based on the username I put.

For example

### Function Get-Lastlogon (USERNAME)

Output to print the following:

1. Username
2. Email address
3. Lastlogon

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you a good read about [`Functions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/09-functions?view=powershell-7.1) on PowerShell, once you have a basic to medium understanding you can move on to [`Advanced Functions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-7.1).

You can try using this one and see if it works for you, though, for the future and specially when working with Active Directory you'll want to have a good knowledge on PS as it is very useful and will make your life easier.

```
function Get-LastLogon {
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
    [parameter(mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    [string]$User,
    [switch]$Wildcard
)

    begin
    {
        $dom = (Get-ADRootDSE).defaultNamingContext
    }

    process
    {
        $param = @{
            LDAPFilter = "(|(name={0}$User{0})(samAccountName={0}$User{0}))" -f $(
                if($Wildcard){ "*" }
            )
            Properties = "lastLogon", "mail"
        }

        if(-not($adUsr = Get-ADUser @param))
        {
            Write-Warning "Cannot find an object with identity: '$User' under: '$dom'"
            return
        }

        $props = @(
            @{n = 'Username'; e = 'samAccountName'}
            @{n = 'Email Address'; e = 'mail'}
            @{n = 'Last Logon Date'; e = {[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogon)}}
        )

        $adUsr | Select-Object $props
    }
}
```

---

**Usage**

```
PS \> Get-LastLogon user.example
PS \> Get-LastLogon user -Wildcard
PS \> Get-LastLogon user.example | Out-GridView
PS \> 'user1', 'user2', 'user3' | Get-LastLogon | Out-GridView
PS \> 'user1', 'user2', 'user3' | Get-LastLogon -Wildcard
```

Note that, the `-Wildcard` switch will add `*` to your `LDAPFilter` i.e.:

```
(|(name=*john*)(samAccountName=*john*))
```

Meaning that, it will find all users having, `john` in this case, contained in their `samAccountName` or `Name` AD attributes.